# Display which and how many variables correspond to conditions

Tags: r, dataset, classification, categories, data-manipulation

I have a dataset divided into passenger names and their status (suppose, 10 cateogories) like this.

| Passenger | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | Captain |
| Mary | Mrs. |
| Claudette | Mrs. |
| Marius | Doc. |
| Holmes | Mr. |
| ... | ... |

ecc.

In R, how can I display how many passengers are characterised by a specific Status and who?
I had in mind a table that represented a situation like "*n passengers into the "Mrs." category and their names are "Claudette, Mary ecc."*

(I don't need the whole string message, only the number and their names)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using `dplyr`

```
dummy <- read.table(text = "Passenger   Status
Peter   Captain
Mary    Mrs.
Claudette   Mrs.
Marius  Doc.
Holmes  Mr.", header = T)

dummy %>%
  group_by(Status) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            names = paste0(Passenger, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  mutate(res = paste0(n, ' passengers into the ', Status, "category and their names are ", names))

  Status      n names           res                                                                   
  <chr>   <int> <chr>           <chr>                                                                 
1 Captain     1 Peter           1 passengers into the Captaincategory and their names are Peter       
2 Doc.        1 Marius          1 passengers into the Doc.category and their names are Marius         
3 Mr.         1 Holmes          1 passengers into the Mr.category and their names are Holmes          
4 Mrs.        2 Mary, Claudette 2 passengers into the Mrs.category and their names are Mary, Claudette
```